# My website showing blank pages

Tags: javascript

All the file are there, but still my index page and all other pages are only  showing blank. Is it a virus attack?

When I check the page source code, I'm getting some code, so I don't understand why the pages remain blank. Please refer to [this link](http://pastebin.com/cmwLPmNK) to see the code.

I can't find any script on my files, but still the page source code shows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ak2.imgaft.com/script/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>


<img id="impspacer" alt="" height="1" width="1" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var impspacer = document.getElementById('impspacer');
    if (impspacer) { impspacer.src = '/img.aspx?q=L3MkWGAkAwH5AwL0Zwx5ZQL1BQtjAGp2ZPHlAzpyZ3RmAwtyZwMyWGAkWGV2ovHmpGNyZwMwWGAkZPHlAzIzWGAkZPHlAzLyZ3RyZwMyMlHmpGVjZGHkZQZjZQN0BQZjWGV2L3xyZ3RkWGV2qTpyZ3RyZwM4WGAkWGV2MzqjWGAkZPHlAz56WGAkZFHlAzMjWGAkAFHlAzuhMlHmpGRyZwMjpPHmpIMOWGV2L2tyZ3Rj-1'; }
</script>
```

Can anybody please help me to get out of this.?

Comment: Supply us with better information please. Referring to a link will not do. Quotes and code samples would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

- Replace the codebase on the site with a known clean copy
- Change your FTP password (making sure the new one is strong)
- Run anti-virus and anti malware/spyware scans on all computers that you either do your coding on or that you use to access the site via FTP
- Make sure that any plugins that you use are up to date
- Make sure that the main application's codebase is also up to date